# Omniture: Change page name dynamically

Tags: jquery, event-handling, jquery-tabs, adobe-analytics

Is it possible to treat a tab as a new page (from an Omniture standpoint) and change the page title when the user clicks on a different (jQuery) tab? Essentially, change `s.pageName` when the user navigates between tabs.

Comment: Are you referring to tabs within an individual's browser, or tabs that you have implemented on your web site?

Answer (score 1):

Use a click event to do this:

```
$("#tab1,#tab2,#tab3").on("click", pageToggle);

function pageToggle(event)
  {
  s.pageName = event.target.id;
  }
```